# Select category name with most access in profile

Tags: sql, select, count

I have this tables:

```
Profile:
ID   NAME
---------
1    COMP
2    SEGM
3    PERS

Category:
ID   NAME
---------
1    NEWS
2    IMGS
3    PEPL

Content:
ID  NAME  IDCAT
---------------
1   HI    1
2   CAT   2
3   DOG   2
4   MAN   3
5   TUT   2

Access:
ID IDCONT IDPRF
--------------
1     3     1
2     5     2
3     3     2
4     2     2
5     1     1
6     4     2
7     1     3
```

I need a help to build a SQL (i'm using SQL Server) to know, based in access, which category of content is more accessed per profile. I need something like this:

```
IDPRF   NAMECAT
---------------
  1      NEWS
  2      IMGS
  3      NEWS
```

Comment: Given your sample data, what are your expected results?

Comment: Question edited, please see the changes and thanks for helping.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but in your sample data, you'd have ties for profile id = 1.  What should display in that case?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand your question? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is an aggregation query where you want the highest count.  You can get this using `row_number()` in SQL Server:

```
select idprf, c.name
from (select a.idprf, c.name, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by a.idprof order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from access a join
           content co
           on a.idcont = co.id join
           category c
           on co.idcat = c.id
      group by a.idprf, cname
     ) ac
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. But what's seqnum in where?

Comment: @LucasMüller seqnum is the aliased column name of the row_number() windowing function. It partitions the rows by profile (idprof), orders them by count from the access table desc, and then numbers them (so highest count = 1, 2nd highest = 2, etc.). Then from that set you filter to where seqnum =1 (ie has the highest count by profile and name.)